# Insert a series of date into sql startdate and enddate

Tags: sql, date, between

I have been working on an SQL Statement in which I can select a start date and end date and add all the dates in between into the table. This start and end date is accompanied by an id. Like for example I select 1/1/2012 and 4/1/2012 and the id is 1
the result should be as follow

```
reqId   reqDate
1       1/1/2012
1       2/1/2012
1       3/1/2012
1       4/1/2012
```

My sql statement is as follow

```
"Insert into Request(reqId, reqDate) " & _
"Select @request, reqDate From Request where reqDate between @start and @end "
```

It just does nothing so I am not sure if I am on the right track.

Comment: How is your magical made up statement meant to know that you want daily intervals rather than, say, hourly or weekly? Also, what RDBMS?

Comment: I have read up on different methods to them but to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not knowing what database system you're using, here's one for SQL Server (2008 or later):

```
declare @Start date
declare @end date
declare @request int

set @Start = '20120101'
set @end = '20120104'
set @request = 1

;with Dates as (
    select @request as reqId,@Start as reqDate
    union all
    select reqId+1,DATEADD(day,1,reqDate) from Dates
    where reqDate < @end
)
select * from Dates
```

Result:

```
reqId       reqDate
----------- ----------
1           2012-01-01
2           2012-01-02
3           2012-01-03
4           2012-01-04
```

(I originally said for 2005 or later, then realised I'm using `date`. For 2005, replace `date` with `datetime`)

Comment: I am actually using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Visual Studio isn't a database system - but most of the obvious ways of connecting to a database from it will connect you to SQL Server (Express or Compact)

Comment: Sorry I am actually a noob in SQL programming. Is there any other ways like using While Loop? I have tried and modify your code but to no avail.

Comment: @LouisLam - people new to SQL frequently go looking for loops, and are surprised not to find them. This is because SQL is intended to be a set-based language - where you describe the overall result, and SQL computes it all in one go. In fact, in my answer, there is something a *bit* like a loop - A [Recursive Common Table Expression (CTE)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx)